# inserting separate lists into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to run the amazon aws alexa api script to get rank of a list of domains.

here is what I have

```
    public static function parseResponse($response) {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response,null,false,
                                'http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11');
    if($xml->count() && $xml->Response->TrafficHistoryResult->Alexa->count()) {
        $info = $xml->Response->TrafficHistoryResult->Alexa;
        $nice_array = array(
                'Date'          => $info->TrafficHistory->HistoricalData->Data->Date,
                'Rank'          => $info->TrafficHistory->HistoricalData->Data->Rank,
        );
    }
    foreach($nice_array as $k => $v) {
        echo $_GET['domain']. $k . ': ' . $v ."\n <br>";
          {INSERT QUERY WILL GO HERE}
    }
}
```

I have a list of 20 domains. I need to create a script that will get the rank of each domain for the last 3 months. so date will start with 2012-09-01 then 2012-10-01 then 2012-11-01. Date is defined earlier in this aws script.

my question. How can I have the script determine the date then use the list of domain names to get rank and then insert into mysql table

Comment: No one will be able to help you with your SQL unless we know what the table looks like.

Comment: table only has 3 columns Date Rank Domain - nothing else

Comment: basically im trying to figure out a loop instead of having to create an INSERT INTO for each domain.